# GAMMs: Implementing a 3-way interaction with categorical variables (i.e. 2 x 2 x 2) using binary difference smooths

Tags: r, categorical-data, interaction, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am attempting to construct a model which conceptually includes an interaction of three 2-level categorical factors, following the guidance of Wieling’s 2018 GAMMs tutorial to recode the factors as binary numeric variables.
The datatset includes a binary accuracy DV `acc` which is measured over time `Trial`. The predictors of interest are three 2-level factors,  `Talker` (NE, NS, ref: NE) and `Predictability` (LP, HP, ref: LP), as well as participant `Group` (YNH, ONH, ref = YNH). I’m including random smooths for `Subject` and `Code` (aka item).
Following the recommendations made by Wieling, I have constructed binary variables as follows, to represent the `Talker`- difference for the reference groups (i.e. NE/HP/YNH - NS/HP/YNH), and the difference of the difference (i.e. [NE/HP/YNH - NS/HP/YNH] - [NE/HP/ONH - NS/HP/ONH]), respectively:

`dat$Is_NS = (dat$Talker == "NS")*1`

`dat$Is_NS_ONH = (dat$Group == "ONH" & dat$Talker == "NS")*1`

The natural extension for the difference-of-the-difference-of-the-difference, then would be:

`dat$Is_NS_HP_ONH = (dat$Predictability == "HP" & dat$Talker == "NS" & dat$Group == "ONH")*1`

My model is as follows:

```
acc.model = bam(acc ~ Predictability +   
               s(Trial, by = Predictability, k=20, m=1) +  
               s(Trial, by = Is_NS, k = 20, m=1) +  
               s(Trial, by = Is_NS_ONH, k = 20, m=1) + 
               s(Trial, by = Is_NS_HP_ONH, k=20, m=1) + 
               s(Trial, Subject, bs = ‘fs’, m=1)+
               s(Trial, Code, bs = 'fs', m=1),
             family = binomial,
             method = "fREML",
             discrete = T,
             data = dat)
```

It runs successfully, and examination of the smooth plots suggests that the model is capturing what I see in plots of the raw data, but I hesitate to use this model for certain without seeing any other examples of this type of analysis.  The output looks as follows:

```
Family: binomial
 Link function: logit

 Formula:
 acc ~ Predictability + s(Trial, by = Predictability, k = 20,
     m = 1) + s(Trial, by = Is_NS, k = 20, m = 1) + s(Trial,
     by = Is_NS_ONH, k = 20, m = 1) + s(Trial, by = Is_NS_HP_ONH,
     k = 20, m = 1) + s(Trial, Subject, bs = "fs", m = 1) +
     s(Trial, Code, bs = "fs", m = 1)

 Parametric coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
 (Intercept)        2.6675     0.1499  17.798  < 2e-16 ***
 PredictabilityHP   0.7879     0.1290   6.108 1.01e-09 ***
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                                edf    Ref.df  Chi.sq  p-value    
 s(Trial):PredictabilityLP    3.635e+00     19  11.546  0.00086 ***
 s(Trial):PredictabilityHP 4.958e-05     19   0.000  0.65023    
 s(Trial):Is_NS            1.000e+00      1  30.848 2.79e-08 ***
 s(Trial):Is_NS_ONH        1.000e+00      1   2.898  0.08871 .  
 s(Trial):Is_NS_HP_ONH     1.000e+00      1  10.672  0.00109 **
 s(Trial,Subject)          2.740e+01    269 158.595  < 2e-16 ***
 s(Trial,Code)             1.102e+02   1165 253.887  < 2e-16 ***
 ---
 Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

 R-sq.(adj) =  0.147   Deviance explained = 20.9%
 fREML = 7134.9  Scale est. = 1         n = 5999
```

Following Wieling’s example, I have tried to reconstruct which smooths are combined to model each of the 8 conditions that are being compared in this 2x2x2 design as a sanity check, but am stuck on some of the conditions. I believe that, in order to model the remaining conditions, I would need to re-level and re-run the model.

```
NE, YNH, LP: Modeled with s(Trial): PredictabilityLP
NE, ONH, LP:
NE, YNH, HP: s(Trial): PredictabilityHP
NE, ONH, HP:
NS, YNH, LP: s(Trial): PredictabilityLP + s(Trial, by = Is_NS)
NS, ONH, LP: PredictabilityLP + s(Trial, by = Is_NS) + s(Trial, by = Is_NS_ONH)
NS, YNH, HP: s(Trial): PredictabilityHP + s(Trial, by = Is_NS)
NS, ONH, HP: s(Trial): PredictabilityLP + s(Trial, by = Is_NS) + s(Trial, by = Is_NS_ONH) + s(Trial, by = Is_NS_LP_ONH)
```

Any feedback on the appropriateness of this approach is greatly appreciated!

(Some other notes/caveats: this model doesn’t include any AR modelling because autocorrelation values have been quite low for this data set.  I’m also aware of using gamm4 for non-gaussian data and am looking into that separately!  I think these questions still hold for gaussian datasets as well)

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If your predictors are categorical, why do you need smoothing?

Comment: @mkt-ReinstateMonica: The predictors that are of interest for this interaction are categorical, but the "main" predictor within the GAMM model (`Trial`) is a continuous variable. The GAMM uses the smooth terms to model `acc` over `Trial`, and I'm trying to model the categorical interactions to account for the fact that I think the time-course of `acc` over `Trial`s changes based on those predictors. Hope that clarifies your question!